# Minimum distance that can be measured using Rplidar A1M8

Tags: arduino, cameras, irobot-create, python, lidar

can you please explain what is the minimum distance that can be measured using RPliadr A1M8

Comment: read the datasheet for the device

Comment: In the future please provide more context for your query. What you think and where you've already looked for information is helpful to make sure that we can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

From [Slamtech's specifications for RPLIDAR A1](https://www.slamtec.com/en/Lidar/A1Spec), you can see that the measuring range is 0.15 m to 12 m.

Normally, the minimum range is related to the light pulse length transmitted, and also the optics (separation and parallax between emitter and receiver).